# Help identify this wing-like piece

Tags: part-identification, star-wars

So I bought a pile of LEGO bricks and I'd like to know what set this piece is from so I can build it. The only clue I have is the set I'm guessing if from around 2015 as I've identified other sets in the pile and they are all 2015 sets.

Looks like a wing from a spaceship? Maybe Star Wars?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [Wedge, 12x3 Left](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=42061&colorID=1) and this sticker pattern is found in [75003-1 A-Wing Starfighter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75003-1) from 2013.

[image]

Comment: And from the looks of it it has been exposed to a lot of sunlight and has significantly yellowed.